# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'input_masks'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a network, but got the error:
AttributeError: in user code:

```
C:\Users\LocalAdmin\.conda\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\keras_contrib\metrics\crf_accuracies.py:23 crf_viterbi_accuracy  *
    mask = crf._inbound_nodes[idx].input_masks[0]

AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'input_masks'
```

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras import Input,Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, TimeDistributed, SpatialDropout1D, Bidirectional, LSTM, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
np.random.seed(1234567890)

#   Neural Network     
input_text = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(ElmoEmbedding, output_shape=(max_len, 961), trainable=False)(input_text)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=496, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1, dropout=0.1))(embedding)
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="relu"))(x)
crf = CRF(n_tags, sparse_target=True)  # CRF layer, n_tags+1(PAD)
out = crf(model)  # output

model = Model(input_text, out)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(np.array(x_train), y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? My python version ist 3.8 and my tensorflow version is 2.4.0.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keras-contrib is [deprecated and unmaintained](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib), and incompatible with TF2:

> Keras-contrib is deprecated. Use TensorFlow Addons.

Use TensorFlow Addons (`tfa`) instead, in your case [`tfa.layers.CRF`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/CRF)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as you. I still have problems after replacing the new version of CRF.
got a error:
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, float16, uint32, uint64

Comment: my code: if args.classifier == 'crf':
            # output = Sequential()
            dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(
                NUM_CLASS, activation=None, kernel_initializer=self.kernel_initializer), name='DENSE')(dec)
            crf = ChainCRF(NUM_CLASS, name='CRF')
            output = crf(dense)
            loss_func = crf.get_loss

        optimizer = optimizers.Nadam(lr=self.lr, clipnorm=args.clip_norm)
        model = Model(inputs=input_node, outputs=output)
        model.compile(loss=loss_func, optimizer=optimizer)
        return model

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31632613)